# How do I avoid the weird gap between search bar and the table view while search results displaying?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Check: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oooX6.png)

I tried solutions to all relevant questions. However none of them helped really.
I am getting a weird gap between table view and search bar when search bar shows results. 
Help me find out what's wrong with my code:
the view controller subclasses from `UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating`

```
var searchController = UISearchController()
var resultsController = UITableViewController()
var refreshController = UIRefreshControl()

in override : 

 configureSearchController()
 resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
 resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
 refreshController.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "")
 refreshController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshSelector), for: .valueChanged)
 tableView.addSubview(refreshController)
 searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
 automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
 definesPresentationContext = true



@objc func refreshSelector()
    {
        if(!searchLoaded)
        {
            searchLoaded = true

            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
            print( "Got ya")
        }
        refreshController.endRefreshing()

    }


func configureSearchController ()
    {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;

        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.searchBarBackgroundGrey()
        searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.searchBarBackgroundGrey().cgColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()



    }
```

deployment target has been set as 9.3

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot? Also iOS target version.

Comment: have you tried unchecking "Adjust Scroll View Insets" on the storyboard?

Comment: @inokey, added.

Comment: @DanielAmarante, yes i tried.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is the tableView style property. If you have a grouped tableView, this gap my come from section header size. Try set header size to 0.1 and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: didnt work @inokey. Any other suggestion?